# Missing csv.reader function in python csv module

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to use the csv.reader function in Python 3.

dir('csv') displays (I have deleted some to shorten the post):

Code:

```
['__add__', ..., 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', ..., 'zfill']
```

What it does not show is 'reader'.

Is there any way to add the 'reader' function to the csv module?

Comment: on further analysis, I see that the program I was trying to run works fine if I copy and paste each line into a python-3 prompt, but if I try to run it through a terminal, I get an error:

Comment: I solved this by restarting my computer...as blhsingh mentions below, the key is to import csv, then dir(csv) -- Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'csv'` is just a string, so when you do `dir('csv')` it just gives you all the attributes and methods available to `str`.

If you do `dir(csv)` (without the quotes) instead you will be able to see all the attributes and methods that the `csv` module has (providing that you have imported the `csv` module first):

```
>>> import csv
>>> dir(csv)
['Dialect', 'DictReader', 'DictWriter', 'Error', 'OrderedDict', 'QUOTE_ALL', 'QUOTE_MINIMAL', 'QUOTE_NONE', 'QUOTE_NONNUMERIC', 'Sniffer', 'StringIO', '_Dialect', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'excel', 'excel_tab', 'field_size_limit', 'get_dialect', 'list_dialects', 're', 'reader', 'register_dialect', 'unix_dialect', 'unregister_dialect', 'writer']
```